# Magento 2 catagory product list image background erased

Tags: magento2, product, product-images, category-products

In category list page the background of product image is erased can you help me and how i can fix that?

*Magento version:* `2.3.4`

[image]

*Orginal Image:*

[image]

Comment: Have you migrated data and images from Magento 1.x?

Comment: @KishorThummar no just uploading it from the admin panel.

Comment: Check my answer, I have resolved the same issue in my past work.

Answer (score 1):

Set ImageMagick as Image Adapter from

> Admin->Stores->Configuration->Advanced->Developer->Image Processing
>   Settings

and set the **ImageMagick** as **Image Adapter**

Install **ImageMagick** on your server if not available, [Check this guide](https://tecadmin.net/install-imagemagick-on-linux/).

Then flush all the cache with **Catalog Image cache** from **Additional Cache Management** on `System->Cache Management page`.

Hope this will help you.